# How to prevent players from moving into objects

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision

After I detect collision, how do I prevent the player from moving into the object? (or even make him push them?) I am using a circular collision detection:

```
self.getDistance = function(pt){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.x-pt.x,2) + Math.pow(self.y-pt.y,2));
    }
```

which works perfect for detecting collision, for example detecting if a bullet hit a player:

```
 for(var i in Player.list){
            var p = Player.list[i];
            if(self.getDistance(p) < 64 && self.parent !== p.id){
                p.hp -=self.damage;
```

but I just can't find a way on how to make the player stop moving into one direction when he is bumping into a wall/another player. Does anyone know how to make that happen?

here is the player movement code:

```
 self.updatepos = function(){

        if(self.pressingRight)
            self.spdX = self.maxSpd;
        else if(self.pressingLeft)
            self.spdX = -self.maxSpd;
        else
            self.spdX = 0;
        if(self.pressingUp)
            self.spdY = -self.maxSpd;
        else if(self.pressingDown)
            self.spdY = self.maxSpd;
        else
            self.spdY = 0; 
        }
```

Comment: We can't tell you without seeing the player model. In your model you should have something akin to `velocity`/`speed` and `direction`/`angle` - in most designs you can simply set the `velocity` to `0` to stop movement.

Comment: Well, you're not providing much code here. I'm guessing the player has to press a button to move. If that is the case, I can think of two ways to handle it. You could include a boolean hasHitWall or something set it to true when the player hits the wall, and in the routine for moving the player, ignore the movement if they have hit a wall. An alternate solution is if you have a variable for player movement speed, change that value to 0 when they hit a wall.

Comment: @bcr666 sorry for not adding the player code.(added it now).
the thing is if i set the velocity (i think in my case its spdY and spdX ) the player will just stop moving at all. I want to stop him from moving into a specific direction